# Is it possible to set a looping animation with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

i am trying to make a slider from scratch, i know there are plugins for this but i want to be able to understand the logic behind it that's why i am building it from the ground up, i've gotten most of the parts down except for the part where i want it to loop once it gets to the last slide.

here is a pen of my work so far
https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/zwoRMy

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function slide() {
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#container").addClass("slide-left1")
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#container").addClass("slide-left2")
}, 9000);

}

slide();
```

what i am looking to do is make a sort of loop maybe with my setTimeout functions as i want each slide to not do anything yet until about a few seconds after page loads and again pause for a few seconds on the corresponding slides so as to give time for visitors to read any content that is on the slide, any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: use `setInterval()` for looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function slide() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#container").removeClass("slide-left3");
      $("#container").addClass("slide-left1");
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#container").removeClass("slide-left1");
      $("#container").addClass("slide-left2");
    }, 4000);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
     $("#container").removeClass("slide-left2");
     $("#container").addClass("slide-left3");
      slide();
   }, 6000);
  }
  
  slide();        
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 300vw;
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: .9s ease;
}

#slide1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .9s ease;
}

#slide2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  transition: .9s ease;
}

#slide3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200vw;
  top: 0;
  transition: .9s ease;
}

.slide-left1 {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.slide-left2 {
  left: -100% !important;
}

.slide-left3 {
  left: -200% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="slide1">
  </div>

  <div id="slide2">
  </div>

  <div id="slide3">
  </div>
</div>
```